# Why is OnlineGDB ignoring the second argument in my member function?

Tags: c++, c++17

The function prototype in the class .h includes 2 arguments, and the function in the class .cpp includes the same 2 arguments, but the compiler pretends it only has 1 (ignoring the second) and prints the following error:

```
 void list::swap(const string[] from, const string[] to)
                                ^~~~
```

`list.cpp:103:6: error: prototype for ‘void list::swap(const string*)’ does not match any in class ‘list’`

```
 void list::swap(const string[] from, const string[] to)
      ^~~~ 
In file included from list.cpp:6:0:
```

`list.h:83:10: error: candidate is: void list::swap(const string*, const string*)`

```
     void swap(const string[], const string[]);
          ^~~~
```

I thought maybe it was a memory issue at first, but I have 26 GB of RAM and only 3GB being used by the web browser. I've tried refreshing and restarting my computer. You can see for yourself with this truncated code:
https://onlinegdb.com/-L_eUQTzY

Comment: You're getting a compiler error, so it has nothing to do with memory. Please make a [mre] The error message indicates a declaration of `list::swap` taking only a single argument.

Comment: It then points to the declaration and shows the line of code it is referring to, which has 2 arguments. When I looked it up before asking this question I found that it most likely occurs from low memory, when the computer fails to give all the code to the compiler.

Comment: Ok, but please read the link in my comment above, and [edit] your question accordingly. Basically, we need to be able to take your code and reproduce the error ourselves.

Comment: Okay. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I specifically made a comment about how the other errors occurring now (that did not happen in the full program) only occur because of the truncation. It cannot be caused by nonexistent errors. But fine, I'll make a mock program with no other errors to further prove the obvious.

Edit: Turns out that wasn't necessary. I thought it was complaining about not having any content, but it was just that I forgot the () in main() when I quickly rewrote the entire main.cpp to give the program of what was already included in the original text.

Comment: @PålHart  Hmm... For some reason onlinegdb is suppressing the first line of the error log, which is the line saying what the first error is. I guess that's why you omitted the first error message in your question? Try a different compiler, one that will not hide the first error message from you.

Comment: Here's an example on Wandbox, showing the first error message, which is the real error: https://wandbox.org/permlink/NGKVPOnyAhTlYSIK

Comment: It is? Yeah I didn't omit anything in my question, that was everything the compiler showed me. This is the only compiler I ever used so I always just thought the first thing was related to the second thing. I wish I could use another compiler, but I have a 2008 Mac Pro running El Capitan for the OS so my options are limi-- well pretty much nonexistent. Maybe I can get Linux Mint or something to replace it...

Comment: "prog.cc:20:32: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'from'" Something between the datatype and its name? That doesn't make sense... Idk what '...' is but ',' separates arguments so I guess it thinks the unnamed part is 1 argument and the name is a 2nd arguments marked incorrectly and ignores everything after that which is causing the next errors... Oh that's right, arrays don't work like pointers in C++ except in prototypes. I have to move the [] to after the name: https://onlinegdb.com/ds1d-vUqW

Comment: @PålHart *"so I always just thought the first thing was related to the second thing"* -- hopefully you now realize that is incorrect, but just to confirm: when gcc (the compiler collection used by onlinegdb) produces an error message, it first reports *what* the error is, then reports *where* the error is. So onlinegdb has told you that there is an error where `from` appears, but does not tell you what the error is (in this case, `const string[] from` should be `const string from[]`).

Answer (score 0):

The brackets have to come after the name:

```
void list::swap(const string from[], const string to[])
```

So it's assuming the first `const string[]` is the passed argument and ignoring everything else on that line because it expects either a ',' or '...' after the arguments name before something else is written.